# How can be change the Dropzone.js maxFileSize?

Tags: asp.net, video, upload, dropzone.js

In my asp.net project, I want to get video with dropzone from the user, in the controller **[RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 699145600)]**
I increased the max upload value using this, I gave the value **maxFilesize: 1000,** for the dropzone configuration,
but values up to 250 mb go through but values larger than that do not. what could be the reason?

I want to upload high size video